# What does the system time represent?

Tags: java, time

When the system time is printed, for example 1331783190854, what time might this be? I'd figure it'd be that many milliseconds (millis was in the code), but the number is too big.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you mean in terms of `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

It's [the number of milliseconds since midnight on 1st January, 1970, UTC.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

Comment: +1 I have been using this method thousands of time, but was ignorant about this. thanks.

Comment: The Java 7 link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, I've updated the answer with the more up-to-date link.

Comment: Google keeps giving me Java 5.0 Javadocs even though it entered EOL almost 4 years ago. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey It all to often throws up the 1.4 docs for me... recurring cycle. They come up in Google so people link to them so they come up in Google ;)

Answer (score 3):

Number of milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970.